# what is an alternative to apply with lambda for faster processing on a large dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, lambda, apply

I have a large (>30M rows) dataframe and I need to create a bunch of columns based on conditions and values of other columns. I have done this before with `apply` and `map` method but it is very inefficient and slow to use it on an entire dataframe this large. I am looking for alternatives that is faster and more scalable.

Here is a header of the dataframe

```
2019_date  | Carrier  | Service_y | ship_from_location
2019-12-17 | USPS     | PM        | ECFC
```

and the code I tried:

```
def cut_off(row):
    if (row['2019_date']>='2019-12-17' and row['Carrier']=='USPS' and row['Service_y']=='FCPS'):
        return 'disable'
    if (row['2019_date']>='2019-12-19' and row['Carrier']=='USPS' and row['Service_y']=='PM'):
        return 'disable'    
    if (row['2019_date']>='2019-12-19' and row['ship_from_location']=='ECFC' and row['Carrier']=='UDSL'):
        return 'disable'
    if (row['2019_date']>='2019-12-19' and row['ship_from_location']=='MWFC' and row['Carrier']=='EMSY'):
        return 'disable'
    if (row['2019_date']>='2019-12-19' and row['ship_from_location']=='ECFC' and row['Carrier']=='LASG'):
        return 'disable'
    if (row['2019_date']>='2019-12-19' and row['ship_from_location']=='beauty_659' and row['Carrier']=='LASG'):
        return 'disable'
    if (row['2019_date']>='2019-12-19' and row['ship_from_location']=='RDR_699' and row['Carrier']=='LASG'):
        return 'disable'
    if (row['2019_date']>='2019-12-22' and row['ship_from_location']=='ECFC' and row['Carrier']=='CDDT'):
        return 'disable'
    if (row['2019_date']>='2019-12-22' and row['ship_from_location']=='beauty_659' and row['Carrier']=='CDDT'):
        return 'disable'
    if (row['2019_date']>='2019-12-22' and row['ship_from_location']=='RDR_699' and row['Carrier']=='CDDT'):
        return 'disable'
    if (row['Normalized_Service'] in (['3D', '1D', '2D']) and row['ship_from_location']=='beauty_659' and row['Carrier']!='UPSN'):
        return 'disable'
    if (row['Normalized_Service'] in (['3D', '1D', '2D']) and row['ship_from_location']=='beauty_489' and row['Carrier']!='UPSN'):
        return 'disable'
    else:
        return 'eligible'

dataframe['eligibility'] = dataframe.apply (lambda row: cut_off (row),axis=1)
```

Comment: Look at `np.select` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column) answer

Comment: Check the answer here using np.select https://stackoverflow.com/a/19913845/8094885